# UDP checksum error c++

Tags: c++, udp, checksum, wireshark

I am calculating UDP checksum using the following function (found it somewhere):

```
   uint16_t udp_checksum(const void *buff, size_t len, in_addr_t src_addr, in_addr_t dest_addr)
     {
             const uint16_t *buf=(const uint16_t *)buff;
             uint16_t *ip_src=(uint16_t *)&src_addr,
                      *ip_dst=(uint16_t *)&dest_addr;
             uint32_t sum;
             size_t length=len;


         // Calculate the sum                                      
         sum = 0;
         while (len > 1)
         {
                 sum += *buf++;
                 if (sum & 0x80000000)
                         sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);
                 len -= 2;
         }

         if ( len & 1 )
                 // Add the padding if the packet length is odd         
                 sum += *((uint8_t *)buf);

         // Add the pseudo-header                                       
         sum += *(ip_src++);
         sum += *ip_src;

         sum += *(ip_dst++);
         sum += *ip_dst;

         sum += htons(IPROTO_UDP);
         sum += htons(length);

     // Add the carries                                              
         while (sum >> 16)
                 sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

         // Return the one's complement of sum                           
         return ( (uint16_t)(~sum)  );
 }



    int form_checksums(char * buff)
    {
      // Get IP and UDP headers
      IP_Header* ipHdr  = (IP_Header*)(buff);
      struct UDP_Header* udpHdr = (struct UDP_Header*) (buff + 4*ipHdr->ihl);

      //---- Form and fill IP checksum now--------------------------------------
      ipHdr->check = 0;
      ipHdr->check = in_cksum((unsigned short *)ipHdr, sizeof(*ipHdr));


      //---- calculate and fill udp checksum now ---
      udpHdr->checksum = 0;

      udpHdr->checksum = udp_checksum(buff + 4*ipHdr->ihl, udpHdr->length, ipHdr->saddr, ipHdr->daddr); 

      return 0;
    }
```

Wireshark shows that the wrong UDP checksum is calculated. I don't see any problem in the function. What can be going wrong?

Comment: I am trying to find the error in this function itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UDP checksum computation requires an UDP **pseudo-header**.

Here are some code samples from my libraries that might help:

```
// SmartBuffer is a stream-like buffer class
uint16_t SmartBuffer::checksum(const void* buf, size_t buflen)
{
    assert(buf);

    uint32_t r = 0;
    size_t len = buflen;

    const uint16_t* d = reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(buf);

    while (len > 1)
    {
        r += *d++;
        len -= sizeof(uint16_t);
    }

    if (len)
    {
        r += *reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(d);
    }

    while (r >> 16)
    {
        r = (r & 0xffff) + (r >> 16);
    }

    return static_cast<uint16_t>(~r);
}
```

The `UDPFrame` checksum computing:

```
uint16_t UDPFrame::computeChecksum(const ipv4_header& ih) const
{
    udp_pseudo_header uph;

    memset(&uph, 0x00, sizeof(uph));

    uph.source = ih.source;
    uph.destination = ih.destination;
    uph.mbz = 0x00;
    uph.type = ih.protocol;
    uph.length = getData()->length;

    systools::SmartBuffer tmp(sizeof(uph) + d_data.size());

    tmp.appendValue(uph);
    tmp.append(d_data); // d_data is the UDP frame payload

    return tmp.checksum();
}
```

Anyway, keep in mind that usually wireshark warns you that a wrong value for the checksum can be computed due to [UDP checksum offload](http://www.cs.duke.edu/ari/trapeze/freenix/node7.html).

Perhaps your checksum function is indeed wrong but a reliable way of beeing sure is to try to receive your UDP frames.

Comment: thanks. I am hoping to find out what's wrong in the function I am already using.

Comment: @SkypeMeSM: Understanding is a good thing but checksum functions are hard to understand. They are designed mostly by mathematicians. If get you get stuck for too long, just try to use my function as it stands. It is know to work. ;)

Comment: Hi, could you please update your answer with a more complete implementation of `SmartBuffer` and `udp_pseudo_header`?

Answer (score 1):

The UDP checksum is usually calculated using a [UDP pseudo header](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/udp.htm#Checksum). This includes a protocol id (17) already in network order. I think you must replace the `sum = htons(17)` by `sum += 17`.

Comment: I changed it to the more standard htons(IPPROTO_UDP). We need htons because we want to add the protocol in byte order. But there is something else wrong in the function. I am unable to find it.

Comment: You should use either the UDP pseudo header approach or the correct _endianess_ when you add the seperate items from pseudo header. The protocol id IPPROTO_UDP must *not* be handled with htons().

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was not working well because I was not filling correctly source and destination address arguments (endianess issues), but the function works well as posted in this question.
You must set checksum to 0xFFFF if the function returns zero.